# Core Data Attribute reset in Swift

Tags: swift, core-data, attributes

In my application, I have set up a Core Data entity called "Finances". For now it has 2 attributes: money and net-worth.

I wish to write a function that each time it is called, it deletes all results for a specific entity. An example might be:

```
    func resetAttribute(attribute: String) {

    }
```

PS: I have found on the internet a function which was engineered to only delete a specific element of an attribute, which matched to a string. I have modified the code in the following way:

```
func resetTest() {
    if let dataAppDelegatde = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate {

        let mngdCntxt = dataAppDelegatde.persistentContainer.viewContext
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "ApplicationFinances")
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "money != %@", "vdavduabsdpansuryiubj")

        fetchRequest.predicate = predicate

        do {
            let result = try mngdCntxt.fetch(fetchRequest)

            print(result.count)

            if result.count > 0 {
                for object in result {
                    print(object)
                    mngdCntxt.delete(object as! NSManagedObject)
                }
            }
        } catch{

        }
    }
}
```

Meaning that if money wouldn't have been equals to vdavduabsdpansuryiubj (Meaning never of course) it would have deleted the other values. But this didn't seem to work.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Your question is ambiguous. Do you want to delete all Finance instances? Or do you want to delete all instances whose property matches a specific value? Or do you want to simply erase one field on all Finance instances? The sample code you posted would delete all instances.

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you run the function? Does it throw an error? Or does it print just fine and runs fine but nothing actually happens when you reload the core data? If this is the case, try adding:

```
do {
    try mngdCntxt.save()
} catch {}
```

Right after the for loop is over

Comment: I tried but it won't work. This other piece of code looks more promising but it won't work either:

        func resetMoneyAttribute(){
    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
    let finances = ApplicationFinances(context: context)
    
    finances.money = nil
    
    do {
    try context.save()
    } catch {
        
    }
}

Comment: @RiccardoPerego does it throw an error? Or just nothing happens in core data stack?